# How is this float affecting the border-radius of my td?

Tags: html, css

I have a td which adds a hover class when I hover the mouse over it:

```
.hover{
    border: 1px solid #364861;
    background: #5979a0 url(img.png) 50% 50% repeat-x;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #ffffff;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

For some reason I can't figure out, the border attribute wasn't taking effect. I randomly added

```
float: left;
```

to the class, and now it works...

It works, so I'm happy, but I don't know why.
I can't recreate the problem in a fiddle, there must be some class somewhere in my DOM that's having an effect on my td. But I just don't know how a float would effect the border-radius of an element.

I did not know these to attributes were linked in any way.

Comment: If you can't duplicate this in a fiddle at the core, then its not the `float` that makes a difference. You'll need to post more code until we can duplicate it when we copy your code into our editors...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because a td cannot have `border-radius`. When you give it a `float` it breaks out of it's table structure and become a seperate element that has it's own structure, so you will see the `border-radius`.

i don't see a use case for a table cell with rounded corners. So it sounds likeyou are misusing the `table`/`td` tags. If it's not table data, don't put it in a `table` structure. Just use `div`'s with rounded corners.